# how to set header font color in Latex

Tags: latex, colors, header

Is it possible to change the header font color in Latex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a look at the `sectsty` package.

> *The secsty package provides a set of commands for changing the fount 1 used for the various sectional headings in the standard LATEX 2ε document classes*

From the manual:

> Make sure you include the package in your document by saying in your
>   document preamble:
>
> > `\usepackage{sectsty}`
>
> You will then have some new commands available. For example:
>
> > `\allsectionsfont{\sffamily}`
>
> will give you sanserif for all sectional headings.

- Here is [the full manual](http://www.cs.brown.edu/system/software/latex/doc/sectsty.pdf)

Comment: When I enter \usepackage{sectsty} I get an error: File 'scetsty.sty' not found. Is there a place where I can download this package?

Comment: Yes, at CTAN: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/sectsty/  Here is a description of how to install new packages: http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/systems/tex/new-packages.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the section heading's font color all at once, then you need to re-define the startsection command.

The following link has a detailed description of customizing sectiong headings' font color,
[Title and Section Headings](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/posters/node4.html)

I have copy pasted the relevant code that needs to be inserted into the preamble,

```
\renewcommand\section{%
\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
              {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
              {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
              {\color{RoyalBlue}\sffamily\Large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsection{%
\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
              {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
              {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
              {\color{RoyalBlue}\sffamily\large\bfseries}}
```

Also, you must remember to import the color package

```
\usepackage{color}
```

Here is the link for more information on colors,
[Color Info](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors#Adding_the_color_package)