# R Markdown PDF Change Font & Color for Headers

Tags: css, r, pdf, latex, markdown

I need to update the color and font of the header (only header) in a R Markdown PDF file. I have found recourses on how to do this for the whole document, but can't find an answer for changing the headers only.

Thank you kindly!

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---
```

Comment: What do you mean with headers? The headline of pages or the  titles of sections etc.

Answer (score 7):

Simplified version of the solution provided by Grada Gukovic:

You can add simple LaTeX statements to your document via the YAML header `header-includes`, e.g.:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{sectsty}
    - \allsectionsfont{\color{cyan}}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for
authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using
R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.
````

Result:

[image]

This is most useful for small additions like the one seen here. If you want to add more than a few lines of LaTeX code it is often easier to save them to an external file, say `preamble.tex` and include that via

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
---
```

Other possible places are `before_body` and `after_body`, c.f. `?rmarkdown::includes`.

Comment: Excellent! Did not know you could do this, thank you kindly for your help!

Answer (score 4):

There is no option to do this in `rmarkdown::pdf_document`. You can do this by modifying the .tex template being used using the `sectsty` package for latex. 
For example the following changes the color of all headers to cyan:

1. Download the default latex template from here: 
   [tex template](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/master/default.latex)
2. Open the template in Notepad and add the following lines on an appropriate place in the document preamble(I have them as lines nr. 200 and 201):

```
    \usepackage{sectsty}
    \allsectionsfont{\color{cyan}}
```

3. Save the modified file with the extension .tex (my file is called "Cyansections.tex") and put it in R's working directory.
4. Modify the header of the .rmd document:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
    pdf_document:
        template: Cyansections.tex
---
```

If you want a different color or font consult this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986473/how-to-set-header-font-color-in-latex)

and `sectsty`'s [manual](http://cs.brown.edu/about/system/managed/latex/doc/sectsty.pdf) Especially section 4 of the manual for chanhing fonts